# How to ensure that ajax response is an object?

Tags: javascript, ajax, null, undefined, typeof

So, I have a jQuery ajax call, and I want to make sure that the response is an object.

my first thought was `if(typeof response === "object")` but there is a problem, if the ajax request returns nothing (but it is hit with a 200 header) then `response` is `null`.

The issue here is that `typeof null === "object"`.

So how can I know that the response is actually a `{}` object?

I guess I could do `if(typeof response === "object" && response !== null)`

But this really seems redundant...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(The below was before your edit saying "I guess I could do...". The `null` check isn't redundant, because it adds new information to the condition.)*

You can explicitly rule out `null`:

```
if (response !== null && typeof response === "object")
```

Note that that will be true for all objects, including arrays.

If you want something that will only be true for `{}` and not arrays or other built-in objects, you can do this:

```
if (Object.prototype.toString.call(response) === "[object Object]")
```

...because `Object.prototype.toString` is defined in the spec as `"[object Null]"` for `null`, `"[object Array]"` for arrays, `"[object Date]"` for dates, etc. Objects created via a constructor function not defined by the spec (unlikely in your case, as you're dealing with deserialized JSON, although if you use a reviver function...) will also come out as `"[object Object]"`. (E.g., if you have `function Foo` in your code and create an object via `new Foo()`, the code above will return `"[object Object]"` for that object, not [sadly] `"[object Foo]"`.)

Note that `Object.prototype.toString.call(response)` is **not** the same as `response.toString()`, because `toString` could have been overridden by `response` or its prototype chain. So we use the `toString` from `Object.prototype` directly, since we know that (barring someone doing something *really stupid* like modifying `Object.prototype`) it will behave as per the spec.

Comment: wonder how much you would break if you injected `Object.prototype = {};` in a page?

Comment: @Hailwood: If before other scripts? Probably everything. :-)

Comment: *writes chrome extension*, *Waits for extension to become popular*, *inserts inject script into extension* Mwhahahaha! :D maybe not!

Answer (score 1):

`I have a jQuery ajax call, and I want to make sure that the response is an object`

Does this mean you can still use jQuery? How about using [$.isPlainObject](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isPlainObject/)?

```
if ($.isPlainObject(response)){ /* */ }
```

Comment: I did not know that function existed, cheers for the answer, and although I am using jquery in this case, sometimes I am not, hence why I have accepted the previous answer, but will keep this one in mind.